# how to delete data if it returns an error using pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda

Hello i'm working on a little project where i'm trying to list all releases of shows by year but the only column i could use for this was a column called "aired" which had a string like this "Oct 4, 2015 to Mar 27, 2016"

since i only needed the year of release aka the first year in this case 2015 but then for all rows in my dataset. for that reason made this line of code.

```
content['airedYear'] = content.aired.str.slice(7,12)
content['airedYear'] = content['airedYear'].str.strip()
content['airedYear'] = pd.to_numeric(content['airedYear'])
```

i used 7 and 12 since if the day of the release had either 1 or 2 digits so i took the substring 1 bigger and then used strip to get rid of the space that would be left either in front or  behind the year (not 100% sure if that fully worked but it seems to work for now).

my actual problem is that some lines did not follow this format at all and they give me error results when i try to convert the column to a numeric value. this is because some lines will have parts of a word instead of the actual year.

how do i change or add to this so i can delete every row that brings up an error since it isn't of use to me.

(in short how do i convert the whole column to a numeric value and if it cannot be converted because it's not a number then just remove the line completely)

thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the error handling `try, except` block.

**NOTE: Please check the type of Error you get when you try to perform the operation. As if you want to delete and a different error comes which is not related to your problem, you might delete the row.**

```
for i in df.index.tolist():
    value = df.iloc[i,index_of_your_col]
    try:
        perform_desired_operation(value)
    except SpecificError:
        df.drop(i)
```

This is a type of scheme that you can follow if you have the knowledge of Python. I hope you got the idea of what to do.

Comment: what do you mean with index_of_your_col. what i tried was putting the name of the column in there which resulted in the following error

ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

Comment: That;s when I stated if you know how to use the pandas. Check at what index your column is located. for example if you have columns like `['a','b','c']` then the index of column named 'c' == 2

Comment: i've now added in the column index instead of name however this is giving me a single positional indexer is out-of-bounds, i don't know why it would give me this error, do you have any clue (the column index is correct since i checked it with the command "content2.columns.get_loc("airedYear")" 

if you want to see here is a link to a  printscreen of the code with error: http://prntscr.com/tcfsk8

also sorry for the amount of problems i'm asking you about, i'm new to using pandas and python and need to get this fixed

Comment: if You are using `pd.to_numeric`, use `error='coerce'` to force the errors to `NaN` and then do `df.drop(subset=[col_name])`. Without `try,except`, do just `df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col],errors='coerce')`   . [see pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Comment: this seems to pretty much fix my issue only thing is it added in some 0.0 values but i just dropped ever row that had that value in it and then the data seems to work.

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Error handling in Python, using try and except should do the job.
However, a nicer solution to yours above is to slice the string left to the word 'to' and there you are left with a clean date.
Does this help?

Comment: i'm not really sure how to go about this with in a data base since i'm not to familiar with using them. i find it confusing how to use the find command while going through the entire data base, also not all of the data will have "to" in it because if it is a movie it will only have the release year.

i can still however do it with something else like ',' but would you care to give me an example of how to use this within data management